# Remember Me feature in spring security core and grails

Tags: grails, cookies, spring-security, remember-me

I am trying to implement 'remember me' feature in my grails application using spring security core. The idea is to login user directly without asking for username and password if the user has logged in earlier. So, I added these codes in my config.groovy file

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.rememberMe.cookieName='sptest_remember_me'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.rememberMe.alwaysRemember=true 
grails.plugins.springsecurity.rememberMe.tokenValiditySeconds=5*60
grails.plugins.springsecurity.rememberMe.parameter='_spring_security_remember_me'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.rememberMe.key='sptest_test'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.rememberMe.useSecureCookie=false
grails.plugins.springsecurity.rememberMe.persistent=false
```

But I am prompted with login screen after the session has expired, I want the application to remember user's login for a month or so. How do I do it ?

Comment: If the action in question is protected by an `IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY` restriction then you'll have to log in again even if you are "remembered".

Comment: Can you please post your session timeout duration? Your remember me token validity duration looks very short for me (5 minutes). And actually if it is less than your session timeout duration then you will not be able use remember me functionality...

Comment: it is protected by 'ROLE_USER' restriction. What can I do so that the user dosen't have to login for the second time ?

Comment: session timeout duration is the default, I have not tampered with it but I increased the token validity duration to 365 days and checked again but I am again redirected to login page.

Comment: @Eddard, have you managed to solve the problem? I am experiencing exactly the same behaviour. My remember me cookie dissapears if I relaunch the browser either if I delete JSESSIONID cookie.

Comment: Same here. Has someone solved this problem in the meantime?